# LSM tree with a row merge function

Tags: java, database, algorithm

I'm looking for a Java library or package or just some code that will help me implement a modified [LSM tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree). Here's the issue:

My system needs to write key/value pairs to a table.

```
key0/value0
key1/value1
```

Later, it will need to add a value to key0.

```
key0/value0.1
```

When my system does a lookup on `key0`, it needs to see "`value0,value0.1`".

In other words, I'm not replacing a record, as an LSM tree typically does, I'm merging it with a previously inserted record. Unfortunately, if I do an update on the record, I lose all of the performance benefits of LSM trees.

Does anyone know of an LSM tree implementation with a merge function, so I can combine rows instead of replacing them?

Or is there a better way of handling this problem?

Comment: You can perform a `read-modify-write` type operation here. First read the old data (i.e., `value0` for `key0` in your case), append new data (i.e., append `value0.1` with the existing value of `key0`), and insert it into LSM as if you are updating the value of `key0`. In that case, you will not need to change your merge function.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/indeedeng/lsmtree/tree/master/lsmtree-core) you will able to find a Java implementation of LSM tree. I am sorry, I will not able to pinpoint the exact merge function from this code, as I am not very familiar with this repo.